# Sublime Text 3: import projects list from folder/files to OpenRecent list

Tags: sublimetext3, workspace

I save several projects in a same folder by manual click `Project -> Save Project As...`
and I used to use `cmd + ctrl + p` to open `Switch Project`list to switch between projects
and everything's works fine.

but today, I accidentally remove my `Switch Project` list in by click `Project -> Open Recent -> Clear Items`, so my `Switch Project` list is empty now...

I know I could add them back through reopen **ALL** my projects. due to the number of projects is pretty a lot, that will be kind of annoying to add them back one by one.

I wanna know if there's a smarter way to do that for me.
maybe import all my `*.sublime-project` files from folder or something.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short of manually opening every project, I don't think there is any way to do something like this directly. There isn't a command or plugin endpoint that I'm aware of that lets you open a project by name or filename, so it's not possible to create a plugin to do the work, and Sublime doesn't have the ability to pre-load the list of packages directly either.

That said, it is possible to manually update the list of recent projects, but whether or not that is more or less work than opening all of the projects is something to consider.

If you use `Preferences > Browse Packages` from the menu or the command palette, a file browser will open on your `Packages` folder. From there go up one directory level and go inside of the `Local` folder, where you will find a `Session.sublime_session` file.

Sublime saves it's state into this file when you quit it, and uses it to restore state when you start it again. Here you will find all of the saved information, such as the windows and files that were open and so on.

Changing this file will change the data that Sublime loads, so you can modify the session file to set up the data that you want. You need to make sure that you modify the file while Sublime is not running or your changes will be ignored and clobbered away. Also it's a good idea to make a backup of the file before you start in case things go pear shaped.

Down near the bottom of the file you will find a  top level key named `workspaces`, and inside of it a `recent_workspaces` key:

```
"workspaces":
{
  "recent_workspaces":
  [
      "/home/tmartin/local/src/OverrideAudit/OverrideAudit.sublime-workspace",
  ]
}
```

This is where the list of recent projects is stored for use in the menu and the quick switch project command. Particular things to notice are that the entries are naming `sublime-workspace` files, and that the paths are absolute.

> **NOTE:** On windows, the filenames stored in the session file are in a format like `/C/Users/tmartin` and not `c:\users\tmartin`; on that platform you need to make sure that you adjust the paths accordingly. As long as there is already at least one entry in the list when you look at the session file, you can easily see how to construct the paths that you need.

Despite the name of the commands and menu items, what you're actually switching between is different workspaces. Every `sublime-project` is associated with a `sublime-workspace` file, which acts as a dedicated `sublime_session` file for that particular project. This mapping is one-to-many in that you can have multiple workspaces for the same project file, allowing you to reference the same paths in multiple windows but have different window layouts.

While Sublime is not running you can edit this file to add in the full paths to all of your workspace files; when you start Sublime up the list will be populated (every `sublime-workspace` file knows what `sublime-project` it is associated with).

What remains is whether or not it's quick to come up with the list of files in a way that you can easily paste them into the session file.

Comment: maybe that's not an intuit solution, but it's great enough to resolve my problem! thanks for the detailed answer!